# What happens to area-effect spells like Darkness or Fog Cloud when an Antimagic Field moves?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

The [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell states that spell effects are "suppressed" in the area of the field.

**Do (non-instantaneous) magical areas of effect take effect again after an *antimagic field* that passes into the area of effect and then leaves it?**

Would a wizard passing through a [*wall of fire*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) in an *antimagic field* permanently leave a gap in the wall, or would the wall restore itself? The same question applies to [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) or [*fog cloud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud). Do those restore themselves?

Does the word "suppress" as opposed to "cancel" or "dispel" suggest that the spell effect returns after the *antimagic field* spell's area is no longer overlapping the other spell's area?

Comment: To clarify, you are only asking about effects that are within the limits of the AMF? Or are you also interested in AoE spells that move like Fog Cloud, which could start on one side of an AMF and want to move through to the other side?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical We are interested in Area of Effects that already exist that an AMF then enters.  (This focus is because it seems a bit more clear what happens if you cast into an area where an AMF already exists. Theoretically the Area of Effect never takes hold in an area where an AMF already exists so as a result - there is no magic there that can return. That said, perhaps those effects also appear - but that could be a different question. It is fine to address that situation as well in an answer but it is not the focus.)

Answer (score 11):

### *Antimagic field* only suppresses areas of effect while they overlap with the field; they function as normal otherwise

The [*antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell description answers your question:

> A 10-foot-radius invisible sphere of antimagic surrounds you. This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse. Within the sphere, spells can't be cast, summoned creatures disappear, and even magic items become mundane. Until the spell ends, the sphere moves with you, centered on you.
>
> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it. A slot expended to cast a suppressed spell is consumed. **While an effect is suppressed, it doesn't function, but the time it spends suppressed counts against its duration.**
>
> [...]
>
> ***Areas of Magic.*** The area of another spell or magical effect, such as *fireball*, can't extend into the sphere. If the sphere overlaps an area of magic, the part of the area that is covered by the sphere is suppressed. For example, the flames created by a *wall of fire* are suppressed within the sphere, creating a gap in the wall if the overlap is large enough.

As  the phrasing of the sentence I've bolded suggests, the area of effect of other spells and magical effects is suppressed only while they overlap with the antimagic field.

Those parts of an AoE outside the area of *antimagic field* are not suppressed (though I'm not sure how it works if the point of origin of a spell like *darkness* is within the area of *antimagic field*). Once either the other AoE is moved or you move (since *antimagic field* is centered on you) such that there is no overlap, there is no AoE in the field to suppress.

This interpretation is further supported by the spell's description of its interaction with creatures/objects summoned or created by magic:

> ***Creatures and Objects.*** A creature or object summoned or created by magic temporarily winks out of existence in the sphere. Such a creature instantly reappears once the space the creature occupied is no longer within the sphere.

As you can see, *antimagic field* doesn't dispel/end the other spell; it simply "suppresses" its effects while the field overlaps the effect of the other spell (or magical effect).