# Can Major Image or Minor Illusion block the view of a beholder's eye stalks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, illusion

I was reading the *Monster Manual* and got to the [beholder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/beholder) (*Monster Manual*, p. 28). It says that the beholder can target three targets it can see.

If I used the [*major image*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image) or [*minor illusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) spells, could they be used to make a wall, and make the eye stalks unusable on anyone behind them?

Comment: Here's a related [question about fog cloud affecting the beholder's eye stalks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128285/does-fog-cloud-render-a-beholders-eyestalks-ineffective)

Comment: I suggest you to explain a bit more about your idea so people can understand where are you coming from and your theory behind it, like the topic with fog cloud.

Comment: Related: [Can an illusion give a player partial cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127454/can-an-illusion-give-a-player-partial-cover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, but there are some concerns.

Unlike [fog cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud), the wall can be circumvented since a wall illusion wouldn't spread the whole 20ft cube like the fog cloud spell. Even so, if it interacts or pass the investigation check, it will be able to see through the illusion. Last but not least, while [major image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image) can make a decent wall, [minor illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) is just too small for that with its 5 feet cube size. The beholder can choose several squares to be looking at you from as a large creature with eyes all around it (with perception +12 nonetheless). Also, same weakness of the previous spell.

But for sure you can force it to get close to you with those spells, even if you get 4 casters to pile up 4 [minor illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) spells to hide behind it.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, but the short answer is no. The long answer is also no, but because the Beholder's central eye casts an antimagic field spell in a 150 foot cone. It would be useless to create illusions at that distance from it.

Comment: Hi Matthew, and welcome to rpg.stackexchange! Check out our [help section](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for things like this [guide to writing great answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Regarding this particular answer, there's a [related question/answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128279/what-happens-to-area-effect-spells-like-darkness-or-fog-cloud-when-an-antimagic/128283#128283) with some interesting information about how antimagic field works, and think about the effects it might have on the eye stalks themselves...

Comment: The illusions would be suppressed as would be the eye rays, forcing the beholder to bite. If he closes the center eye, the illusion is there and he can't see the targets, must approach the illusion anyway.